# Should these questions about the history of the 5-foot square in D&D be merged?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, specific-question, duplicates

Last week, the question [When did 5 foot squares become standard in D&D?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/157391/4462) was marked as duplicate of [When did the 5-foot square/hex become the standard unit of measurement in Dungeons & Dragons?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/21684/4462).

The now-closed question managed to attract a few good answers, and maybe even better than the ones from the 8-year-old question.

**Should we merge these questions?**

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This seems like a great case for merging. The questions are identical. The answers are high quality and will make sense when put together in the same spot.

The moderation team's discussed it internally and we agree a merge is appropriate.

We're going to hold off for a few days in case there's something we missed that means we shouldn't merge these. Merging's difficult to unwind so we need to be careful and conservative in its use, which here means taking time to make sure it's the right choice and there's no problems.

Comment: It's been over a week with no objections, so I've merged them now.